# Show that the sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = (-1)^n \sqrt{5+4x_n}$, where $x_1=1$ has a convergent subsequence. Find it explicitly.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that the sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = (-1)^n \sqrt{5+4x_n}$, where $x_1=1$ has a convergent subsequence.

Completely stuck at it. Please help me with some hints. No need to solve completely, just guide me through it.

I tried to find the subsequences $\{x_{2n}\}$ and $\{x_{2n+1}\}$ but couldn't find any structural formula for it.

**Edit :** I think the question is wrong
$x_2 = (-1)^1 \sqrt{5+4 \cdot1} = -3$
And $ x_2 = (-1)^2 \sqrt{5+4 \cdot(-3)} \in \mathbb{C-R}$

Comment: Use the LaTeX/MathJax  `\cdot` symbol for multiplication, not a grammatical full-stop.

Comment: Already $x_3$ is undefined—or an undetermined complex number $\pm\mathrm i\surd7$ if we are being generous. Continuing with this liberal interpretation, the multiplicity of possibilities (in $\Bbb C$) doubles at each step. Perhaps we are expected  to show that, for an appropriate choice of value at each step, we can get a convergent subsequence. The mathematics isn't simple, and I doubt whether it is on your syllabus. More likely, there is a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|x_1 |\leq 5.$ Assume that for some $k$ $|x_k |\leq 5$  then $$|x_{k+1} |=\sqrt{ 5+ 4x_k } \leq \sqrt{5+4\cdot 5 }=5$$
therefore $x_k$ is bounded by $5$ and therefore has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Yes that's by Bolzano but I'm supposed to find it.. because the original question wants me to prove that the sequence is not convergent and I've to find a convergent subsequence explicitly.

Comment: @Itachi: It's no use putting that in a comment to an answer, is it? Edit your question if that's what you meant to ask.